# how to resolve native element of undefined karma angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

i am getting this error which i cannot resolve at my end i have tried everything 
can anyone please help me resolve this issue

**here is my html file**

```
<ng-template #icd10codes let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
<form role="form" #icdCodeSelectionForm="ngForm" novalidate>
<div class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h5>
 </div>
 </form> 
 <ng-template>
```

**i defined title in ts file**

```
 public title: string = "Please Select ICD-10 Codes";
```

**here is my spec file**

```
BeforeEach(async() => {
fixture = TestBed.createComponent(NewTestOrderICD10CodeSelectionModalComponent);
component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-title')).nativeElement.innerText;
fixture.detectChanges();
});

it("New Test Order ICD10 Coed Selection Modal Should be created", () => {
expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});

it('Should have a title', () => {
//expect(element.textContent).toContain(component.title);
 expect(de).toContain(component.title);
});
```

i am getting the error of native element of undefined 
is there any help to resolve 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
it('Should have a title', () => {
  //expect(element.textContent).toContain(component.title);
  fixture.detectChanges();
  const de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-title')).nativeElement.innerText;    
   expect(de).toContain(component.title);
});
```

make sure you have called `fixture.detectChanges();` before you access the element.  This makes sure that all the angular values are rendered properly before html is rendered/tested

Remove

```
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.modal-title')).nativeElement.innerText;
```

from `BeforeEach` block